# React Jvectormap: Show country tooltip on click

Tags: reactjs, jvectormap

How can I show country tooltip when country is clicked and not on hover?

Solutions I've found are using JQuery, but I'm looking for a React solution. Or, if someone could explain how I could use those solutions in react.